# CSV WriteRow Data

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write 2 variables to the rows in my csv. The `result` variable (which has 2 columns/values), and the 'item`variable (which has just 1 value). Can I include both of these values in the`writerow` function parameter? If so, how would the syntax look? My syntax below with the comma between the two variables doesn't work.

line I'm talking about:

```
writer.writerow([item,result.items()[0][0],result.items()[0][1]])
```

All of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import splunklib.client as client 
import splunklib.results as results
import csv

listOfAppIDs = []
with open('filefolder/filelocation.txt', 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:
        listOfAppIDs.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
listOfAppIDs.sort() #alphebetically sort list

HOST = "ipAddress"
PORT = 1234
USERNAME = "uName"
PASSWORD = "pWord"

startPoint = "firstAppInList" 

outputCsv = open('filefolder/filelocation.csv', 'wb')
fieldnames = ['appID', 'TotalDestinationIPAddresses', 'AverageThroughputPerMonth']
writer = csv.DictWriter(outputCsv, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader(); 

def connect():
    global startPoint , item

    service = client.connect(
        host=HOST,
        port=PORT,
        username=USERNAME,
        password=PASSWORD,
        autologin=True
    )   

    jobs = service.jobs
    kwargs_blockingsearch = {"exec_mode": "blocking"}

    try:
        for item in listOfAppIDs:
            if (item >= startPoint):
                searchquery_blocking = "splunkQuery"
                print item + ':'
                job = jobs.create(searchquery_blocking, **kwargs_blockingsearch) 
            for result in results.ResultsReader(job.results()):             
                writer.writerow([item,result.items()[0][0],result.items()[0][1]])#writes data underneath the column header
    except csv.Error:
        startPoint = item
        connect()

connect()
outputCsv.close()
```

ANSWER:

```
writer.writerow([item,result.items()[0][1],result.items()[1][1]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass multiple fields to `writerow` by passing it an array. Assuming that `result` is an array of two elements, you could do this

```
writer.writerow([item,result[0],[result[1]])
```

or if `result` is an `OrderedDict` as per your comment, you can do this:

```
writer.writerow([item,result.items()[0][0],result.items()[0][1]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. `Result` is actually an ordered dictionary, so how would I called the value of the key/value pair in the first term of the `result` array? Maybe something like `result.keys(0)` and `result.keys(1)`?

Comment: You can get to key/value pairs via `result.items()`

Comment: I have updated the post with @CaptSolo's suggestion.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but sadly, my script won't output the search results from splunk into the output file. I have my updated code I'm using above if you wish to dig into the problem further.

Comment: Are you closing the file handle of your output file ? `outputCsv.close()`?

Comment: I was not before, but I include the `outputCsv.close()` line in my code now. I include a line `except csv.Error` in my code, and it gave me the following error: `ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: queryResult1, queryResult2`

Comment: Thanks for the input. The script worked with the following line: `writer.writerow([item,result.items()[0][1],result.items()[1][1]])`

Answer (score 2):

What error message are you receiving?

When using `csv.DictWriter` a dictionary should be passed to `writerow()`, not a list.  Based on what I see you could use a normal `csv.writer` object and just call `writerow()` with your header row, rather than creating a dictionary for each call to `writerow()`.

So if you initialize it like this I think it will work:

```
writer = csv.writer(outputCsv)
writer.writerow(fieldnames);
```

Comment: it gave me the following error: ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: queryResult1, queryResult2

Comment: I added some code for how to initialize a normal `csvwriter` that means you can use the simpler list with `writerow()`.